# Hacked, Extension Stolen - How To Recover Quickly?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Google account was hacked, and my popular (~200k users) extension was stolen and transferred to a malicious account. The extension was updated with new code and my users are being automatically updated.

I've tried to contact Google 3 different ways, but no response so far. What's the best way to quickly shut down the stolen extension, and get ownership back to me?

I don't want the extension listing and id to be just deleted, because I want to retain all my existing users and thousands of positive reviews.

Has anyone had success with a particular method of contacting Google? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Matt Kruse

Social Fixer

Comment: Try the [official G+ group for extensions](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions).

Comment: I went there. It directed me here. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue.

Comment: Any clue about where to post something like this? I have searched all over. There doesn't seem to be a home for this. The google docs directed questions here.